# Django can not connect to MySQL database over ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, django

I got a simple Django 1.3.* project, i would like to run it over my localhost. 
I installed all necessary modules like: python-mysqldb, rptz etc...
I have ubuntu 10.04 installed with python 2.7.2.
When i tried to start project in terminal

```
thor@thor:/media/SAJAT - Projects/project/simple project$ python manage.py runserver
```

I got the following error message:

```
> Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1224910>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.30.101' (110)")
```

I have no idea where this IP address comes from 172.17.30.101' (110)  because of my mysql server has been installed on my computer(localhost)

Here is my settings.py file

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'dbname',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': 'dbuser',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '123456',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
 #'PORT': '3306', i tried with this too                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
 #'PORT': '3360', i tried with this too                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        },
        # 'read': {
        #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        #     'NAME': 'newsonia',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        #     'USER': 'dbuser',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'PASSWORD': 'dbname',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        #     'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        # }
    }
```

I have no idea how should be resolve this kind of errors.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on a Django-specific forum.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost Django 1.3 has been unsupported for over a year (since 1.5's release, Feb 2013). You should consider it **dangerous** to leave in public-facing circumstances. Ubuntu 10.04 Server will reach that state in less than a year too... So besides your actual problem, you need to consider a infrastructure upgrade.

That your site is connecting to a random-looking reserved (it's not a legal public IP) on the standard POP3 port. I can't see any circumstance where this could happen accidentally. Something in your setup is *causing* this to happen.

My money's on your settings, like another definition of `DATABASES` that you haven't noticed. Confirm this by adding this to one of your views:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings['DATABASES']
```

And see what comes out the other side. From there it's just finding the problem.

Failing that

- Check that old `DATABASE_*` settings aren't interfering in a similar method
- Trace the connection back through the MySQL module code. You can see what's going on in your trace. Track that back (inserting print statements if you have to) until you get to the point where your connection is being formed.